# Running Wordpress as an Application on a Service instead of a VM with AWS

Tags: wordpress, azure, amazon-web-services, azure-marketplace

I currently running WordPress installed on a VM's hosted by Azure and looking into migrating from using Virtual servers to hosting a WebApp for our WordPress site rather than having to upgrade the everything on the server when its build gets obsolete.

I am aware of the Azure Marketplace Wordpress Application option, but I was wondering if AWS had something similar or what its closest equivalency would be rather than just creating an EC2 VM.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic, as you're asking for product recommendations. Definitely not a programming question, and seems like something you can trivially look up via the AWS portal.

Comment: Server configuration questions are common here and useful to developers as they are "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Arguably any question here could be answered elsewhere on a niche forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run Wordpress on AWS, it means running it on an EC2 instance, which is pretty much the same as you are already doing on a Azure VM.

Comment: This might fit as a comment, but it's not an answer: The OP asked about non-VM solutions, to avoid VM maintenance. The question itself is off-topic anyway, since not even a programming question, just a tool recommendation question.

Comment: He asked about non-VM solutions available in AWS for running wordpress, and the answer is: there are none.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is now on Azure Market place and you don't need a VM to host your WordPress.

It will just create a Web Site in Azure and installs WordPress there, then you can make your changes to the WordPress instance if you wish:

[image]

use this link to get started:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/wordpress/wordpress/

This way you don't need to worry about the VM management and you just use a hosting service and have the benefits of Cloud like Scaling out/up etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was aware of the Azure WebApp option though. I was wondering if AWS had something similar or what it's closest equivalency would be. (I'll be sure to edit the question)